# How to fire off the rule in this example?

Tags: clips

I'm trying to build a simple expert system for recommending courses and want to implement certainty factor in my program, however I'm stuck looking for a simple integration method.

I've stumbled upon [this example](http://www2.cs.siu.edu/~rahimi/cs437/slides/certaintyFactor.pdf) but can't seems to figure out how to make it fire.

```
; Allow facts that are duplicates:
(defrule start
(declare (salience 1000))
(initial-fact)
=>
(set-fact-duplication TRUE))

(defrule combine-certainities-both-positive
?fact1 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C1&:(>= ?C1 0))
?fact2 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C2&:(>= ?C2 0))
(test (neq ?fact1 ?fact2))
=>
(retract ?fact1 ?fact2)
(bind ?C3 (- (+ ?C1 ?C2) (* ?C1 ?C2)))
(assert (organism ?attribute ?value ?C3)))

(defrule combine-certainities-both-negative
?fact1 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C1&:(< ?C1 0))
?fact2 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C2&:(< ?C2 0))
(test (neq ?fact1 ?fact2))
=>
(retract ?fact1 ?fact2)
(bind ?C3 (+ (+ ?C1 ?C2) (* ?C1 ?C2)))
(assert (organism ?attribute ?value ?C3)))

(defrule combine-certainities-with-opposite-signs
?fact1 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C1)
?fact2 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C2)
(test (< (* ?C1 ?C2) 0))
(test (neq ?fact1 ?fact2))
=>
(retract ?fact1 ?fact2)
(bind ?C3 (/ (+ ?C1 ?C2) (- 1 (min (abs ?C1) (abs ?C2)))))
(assert (organism ?attribute ?value ?C3)))
```

I try to assert two new organism facts to kick start the first rule:

```
CLIPS> (assert (organism morpholgy1 rod1 0.25)
(organism morpholgy2 rod2 0.25))
==> f-4     (organism morpholgy1 rod1 0.25)
==> f-5     (organism morpholgy2 rod2 0.25)
<Fact-5>
CLIPS> (run)
<== Focus MAIN
0 rules fired        Run time is 0.00300693511962891 seconds.
0.0 rules per second.
2 mean number of facts (2 maximum).
0 mean number of instances (0 maximum).
0 mean number of activations (0 maximum).
```

And use the matches but still don't get how to make it match here..

```
CLIPS> (matches combine-certainities-both-positive)
Matches for Pattern 1
f-4
f-5
Matches for Pattern 2
f-4
f-5
Partial matches for CEs 1 - 2
 None
Activations
 None
(4 0 0)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute and the value have to match (morpholgy1 != morpholgy2 and rod1 != rod2). That's why fact duplication has to be enabled to allow multiple copies of the same attribute/value.

```
CLIPS> (set-fact-duplication TRUE)
FALSE
CLIPS> 
(assert (organism morpholgy rod 0.25)
        (organism morpholgy rod 0.25))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (run)
<== f-2     (organism morpholgy rod 0.25)
<== f-1     (organism morpholgy rod 0.25)
==> f-3     (organism morpholgy rod 0.4375)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was reading this line: (defrule combine-certainities-both-positive
?fact1 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C1&:(>= ?C1 0))
?fact2 <- (organism ?attribute ?value ?C2&:(>= ?C2 0))
(test (neq ?fact1 ?fact2)), I thought the pattern to match here would be to match two organism and since attribute and value are both variables, they don't really matter as long as both CF for the two organisms are over 0? Otherwise don't quite understand the meaning of stacking up the facts like this. 